# MySQL Finding data using IN and LIKE Wildcard

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

How would I go about doing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE people IN ('Jack', '%Bob%')
```

Finding all fields that either equal 'Jack' or contain 'Bob'? I don't think my example is the proper syntax because it's not pulling up any records.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server using wildcard within IN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076097/sql-server-using-wildcard-within-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE people='Jack' OR PEOPLE LIKE '%Bob%'
```