# SQL OR statement in Wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard, sql-like

My current MySql wild card is `LIKE '%A%B%'`. This can return values that contain A **and** B.

Can anyone suggest how can I alter the wildcard statement to return values that contain either A **or** B.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do something like `LIKE '%A%' or columnname LIKE '%B%'` . It might not be accurate. but give it a try

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is there any other way to get the result by just altering the wildcards. @stack

Comment: No, there is not, at least not with the `like` operator. With `rlike` operator it is possible to do it.

Comment: @User420: I m not sure about any other way. but the syntax which I gaved you works perfectly(_tested_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many `like` operator you want within the parenthesis with OR condition like below

```
select * from tablename where (column_name  like '%test%' or same_column_name  like '%test1%' or 
            same_column_name  like '%test2%' or same_column_name  like '%test3%')
```

For more info have a look at the below link.

[SQL Server using wildcard within IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076097/sql-server-using-wildcard-within-in)

Hope that helps you

Comment: Indeed. This does work. However there is a major performance drawback. Both REGEXP and LIKE '%something%' are notoriously slow. So combining them makes things worse.

Comment: I totally agree with you on this. But other than this, I didn't find any way to help OP. May be some senior people here and figure out

Comment: no worries. I didn't think this was a bad answer.  +1 from me

Comment: Thanks and appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

```
 select * from Table1 where some_column REGEXP '[AB]'
```

there are lots of different ways in writing this as a regular expression, the above basically means containing A or B.

Generally you want to avoid using REGEXP and LIKE '%something' because the do not use indexes. Thus for large tables these operations would be unusable. When you want to do a search of this kind it's always best to stop and ask: "Have I got the best database design?", "Can I use full text search instead?"