# Pulling in all contacts with specific postal codes using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pull in all contacts whose postal code begins with L5h, K2S or L3S.

My sql is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [customer_list_DE]
WHERE Postal_Code IN ('L5H%','K2S%','L3S%')
```

I have checked my data and many records exist with postal code that start with those characters, but my query is resulting in 0 records (however it is not erroring out). I am using Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server using wildcard within IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076097/sql-server-using-wildcard-within-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `OR`.  `IN` doesn't do wildcards:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [customer_list_DE]
WHERE Postal_Code = 'L5H%' OR Postal_Code = 'K2S%' OR Postal_Code = 'L3S%';
```

You could also do this with string manipulation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [customer_list_DE]
WHERE LEFT(Postal_Code, 3) IN ('L5H', 'K2S', 'L3S')
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` list does not support wildcards. Use `OR` instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [customer_list_DE]
WHERE Postal_Code LIKE 'L5H%'
   OR Postal_Code LIKE 'K2S%'
   OR Postal_Code LIKE 'L3S%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM [customer_list_DE]
WHERE Postal_Code LIKE 'L5H%'
   OR Postal_Code LIKE 'K2S%'
   OR Postal_Code LIKE 'L3S%';
```